# Unable to find adabas jdbc driver

Tags: java, jdbc, mainframe, adabas

I'm trying to connect adabas database from java. 
I have installed adabas database but i couldnty find a driver to connect to this db from java.
Can anyone share the link or url where i can download adabasd.jar.

Comment: Who is Upvoting an off-topic question?

Answer (score 0):

i know one proprietary driver at attunity. You can try the evaluation version from this site: http://www.attunity.com/products/attunity-connect/jdbc-drivers.